# How do I set signal handler to multiprocessing.Process?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, selenium, multiprocessing, signals

How can I set signal handler in target function?

multiprocessing.Process (cur_process in GUI) object would created and start when user click start button.

After that when user click stop button, I need to kill process gracefully.(send SIGTERM to cur_process when click stop button)
However, I am using Webdriver, so I want to quit Webdriver before kill process.
So I tried set signal handler in target function (`test_main`) but does not handle SIGTERM despite click stop button.

How I can set signal handler in Process target function?

```
import tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import Process
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys
import signal
import time
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def create_driver():
    options = Options()
    if sys.platform == "darwin":
        options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary'
    #options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        options.binary_location = "C:\\(user_home)\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe" #location of chrome canary for windows
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    #options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--reduce-security-for-testing')
    options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        chromedriver_path = r".\chromedriver"
    else:
        chromedriver_path = "./chromedriver"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, chrome_options=options)
    return driver



class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.cur_process = None
        self.pack()
        self.create_widget()

    def create_widget(self):
        self.start = tk.Button(self, width=5, padx=10, pady=3)
        self.start["text"] = "Start"
        self.start["command"] = self.start_event
        self.start.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2, padx=4, pady=10)
        self.quit = tk.Button(self, width=5, padx=10, pady=3)
        self.quit["text"] = "Stop"
        self.quit["command"] = self.stop_event
        self.quit.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2, padx=4, pady=10)

    def start_event(self):
        if self.cur_process is None:
            self.cur_process = Process(target=test_main) #target function
            self.cur_process.start()

    def stop_event(self):
        if self.cur_process != None:
            os.kill(self.cur_process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
#            self.driver.quit()
            self.cur_process = None


def test_main(): #target function
    # set signal handler to SIGTERM
    def k():
        print("set new signal handler")
        try:
            driver.quit()
            # then terminate process
        except NameError:# driver is not defined
            pass # do nothing
        sys.exit() # terminate process
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, k)
    # do something with driver
    driver = create_driver()
def gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x300")
    g = GUI(master=root)
    g.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui()
```

Comment: Windows doesn't have POSIX signals, so `kill(pid, SIGTERM)` is implemented via `TerminateProcess`, which is like a Unix `SIGKILL`. If you're running via python.exe with an attached console, you can broadcast `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` to all processes attached to the console via `os.kill(0, signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)`. The CRT maps this event to `signal.SIGBREAK`. You'll also have to handle or ignore `SIGBREAK` in the main program since the default action is to call `ExitProcess`.

Comment: Note also that Python executes signal handlers on the main thread. If the main thread is blocked or executing compiled machine code from an extension module, then  Python will never get a chance to call the registered signal handler. In that case, at least on Windows, you can instead use ctypes to set a low-level console control handler via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`.

Comment: In Linux, how to use low level api?